Issue with Selenium IntelliJ
I have the following error in intelliJ when run my code, no matter debug or not:
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for 127.0.6533.119. You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.18.1 where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
I use JDK v21.0.4.and ChromeDriver v120.0.6099.109
I try to input dependency in POM.xml, without change.
Should i go back to an older version of Crome?

It may be that you have some kind of error in your pom.xml. Perhaps you should [edit] your question and post the contents of your pom.xml? Remember to post it as formatted text and not as an image.

Here is my pom.xml code ---> https://codeshare.io/k0NN0V
